# Mule ESB CE 3.5.0 TCP Reconnection Strategies

Tags: sockets, tcp, mule, esb

I am working with Mule ESB CE 3.5.0 and am seeing what I believe is a resource leak on the TCP connections. I am hooking up VisualVM and checking the memory. I see that it increases over time without ever decreasing.

My scenario is that I have messages being sent to Mule, Mule does its thing, and then dispatches to a remote TCP endpoint (on the same box, usually). What I did was not start up the program that would receive a message from Mule's TCP outbound endpoint. So there is nothing listening for Mule's dispatched message.

I configure my TCP connectors as following:

```xml
<tcp:connector name="TcpConnector" keepAlive="true" keepSendSocketOpen="true" sendTcpNoDelay="true" reuseAddress="true">
    <reconnect-forever frequency="2000" />
    <tcp:xml-protocol />
</tcp:connector>

<tcp:endpoint name="TcpEndpoint1" responseTimeout="3000" connector-ref="TcpConnector" host="${myHost}" port="${myPort}" exchange-pattern="one-way" />
```

My questions are:

1. When a flow fails to send to the TCP outbound endpoint, what happens to the message? Is the message kept in memory somewhere and once the TCP connector establishes connections to the remote endpoint, do all the accumulated messages burst through and get dispatched?
2. When the reconnection strategy is blocking, I assume it is a dispatcher thread that tries to establish the connection. If we have more message to dispatch, then are there more dispatcher threads that are tied up to attempting the reconnection? What happens if it is non-blocking?

Thanks!

Edit:

If I also understand [the threading documentation correctly](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance), does that mean that if I have the default threading profile set to poolExhaustedAction="RUN", and all the dispatcher threads block waiting for a connection, eventually the flow threads, and then the receiver threads will block on trying to establish the connection. When the remote application begins listening again, all the backlogged messages from the blocked threads will burst through.

So if the flow receives transient data, it should be configured to have non-blocking reconnection and since it is acceptable to throw away the messages (in my use case), then we can make do with the exception that will be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would point you to the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Reconnection+Strategies):

> Non-Blocking Reconnection
>
> By default, a reconnection strategy *will block Mule application
>   message processing* until it is able to connect/reconnect. When you
>   enable non-blocking reconnection, the application does not need to
>   wait for all endpoints to re-connect before it restarts. Furthermore,
>   if a connection is lost, the reconnection takes place on a thread
>   separate from the application thread. Note that such behavior may or
>   may not be desirable, depending on your application needs.

On blocking reconnection strategies what you are going to get is that the dispatcher will get blocked, waining for an available connection. The messages are not technically kept anywhere, their flow is just stopped.

Regarding the second question it changes between transport and transport. In this very special case, given that tcp is a connection per request transport, different dispatchers will try to [get](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/tcp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/tcp/TcpMessageDispatcher.java#L43) a different socket form the pool of [connections](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/tcp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/tcp/TcpConnector.java#L195).

In case of non-blocking strategies you will get an exception. You can probably test it easily.